# How to sync two columns and update the following cells in the rows?

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, libreoffice-calc

Say I have two files, which have first columns are identical:

[image]

Note, that only the first columns are synced. The second columns are different.

*Is there a way to make a rule between two files that,*

1. Column 1 in file 2 will be rearranged/modified/added exactly whenever the column 1 in file 1 be rearranged/modified/added
2. The rows in file 2 with match with the new arrangement?

For example, after the rearrange in file 1 (`Dog Cat Horse Mouse` → `Dog Mouse Horse [Empty] Cat Chicken`), the first column in file 2 will be exactly the same, and the rows that go with `Mouse`, `Horse`, `Cat` will swap their positions accordingly.

[image: 2020-04-03_22-17-40.png]

The value 5 is added later. I just illustrate here that if Chicken has value 5, and then later if Chicken is rearranged to other place, its whole row should be arranged as well.

I'm using both Excel and LibreOffice Calc.

Comment: Hi @Ooker,, even I've tried my best to edit the post but still I'm confused that what exactly you are looking for,, please [Edit] your post & share the expected output with us, will help use to fix it !!

Comment: thank you for your effort. I've edited it, can you check it?

Comment: Hey @Ooker,, still it's not clear but yes what I'm getting is that you need to add 3rd column in `File 1` and input numbers for pets and in `File 2`,, to get the appropriate pet numbers use lookup formula in column next to pets name !

Comment: But how would the program know that the value for `Chicken` in File 2 is 5? Does that come from some other list, or do you write it after changing File 1?

Comment: @JimDanner yes the value 5 is added later. I just illustrate that if Chicken has value 5, and then later it's rearranged to other place, the value should follow it as well

Comment: @RajeshS that would work, but here I want the whole row to swap position as well, not just the second column. There can be unlimited column in use here

Comment: @Ooker,, better you [edit] post & share real data along with expected output,,, or upload file on cloud,,, like DropBox,, Google Drive .